# Select Statement in SQL inheritance

Tags: sql, sqlite

CREATE TABLE User(
UserID int primary key,
Name varchar,
type int
);

CREATE TABLE Student(
UserID int primary key references User(UserID),
marks int
);

CREATE TABLE Lecture(
UserID int primary key references User(UserID),
salary int
);

Can someone help with with select statement for Student or lecture.

Both Lecture and Student tables are inheriting from User table,So I need to know how insert data and select data from these tables.

Comment: please add more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query the tables, this would work:

```
SELECT         u.[Name]
                 , s.marks
                 , l.salary
    FROM           [User]  u
        INNER JOIN Student s
            ON u.UserId = s.UserId
        INNER JOIN Lecture l
            ON u.UserId = l.UserId;
```

However, if there are no records in the Student / Lecture tables yet, you should use `LEFT Join` instead.

As for inserting the data, you would need to use [SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```
Insert into [User] (Name) values ('Melvin')
```

Get the identity of the `UserId`

```
DECLARE @userId INT;
SELECT @userId = SCOPE_IDENTITY ();

INSERT INTO Student
(
    UserID
  , Marks
)
VALUES
(userId, 5);
```

Update: Just noticed this was SQL Lite, which I'm not so familiar with, but it looks like it supports `last_insert_rowid()` instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY (), but you should get the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select Student X:

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE UserID = X
```

If you want to select all Students and their User data, you'll want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM User
  JOIN Student ON User.UserID = Student.UserID
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your question but I think you need something like that

```
select Name, marks
from User as u, Student as s
inner join u.UserID == s.UserID;
```

Comment: (1) you don't understand the question, (2) you posted an answer with code that does not even run and (3) your answer is upvoted!